# Truncate Datetime to Second (Remove Milliseconds) in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, datetime

What is the best way to shorten a  datetime that includes milliseconds to only have the second?

For example `2012-01-25 17:24:05.784` to `2012-01-25 17:24:05`

Comment: Side note: in my case I was really interesting in comparing dates, but ignoring tiny differences (in order to find fuzzy matching records). It made better sense to find where `DATEDIFF(SECONDS...)` was less than 1.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This will truncate the milliseconds.

```
declare @X datetime
set @X = '2012-01-25 17:24:05.784'
select convert(datetime, convert(char(19), @X, 126))
```

or

```
select dateadd(millisecond, -datepart(millisecond, @X), @X)
```

[CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)
[DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
[DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Comment: The second solution, subtracting the milliseconds, is brilliantly simple.

Answer (score 25):

*The* fastest, also language safe and deterministic

```
DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, '20000101', getdate()), '20000101')
```

Comment: A nice option, but then I have to convert it back from (not sure what to call your example since it is not 1970 -- unix time) to have a human readable timestamp.

Comment: I used 2000 to avoid integer overflow. You can use 19700101 if you want

Comment: Used this in the past when I want to group by certain MS, say every 40 MS -- really wish it was big int sometimes.

Comment: This is very fast indeed. Problem is that it returns the wrong result. Maybe if you replaced dd with second

Comment: @MikaelEriksson no, try running it a million times. This is twice as fast.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: feel free to edit my answers for bleeding obvious typos :-)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - No not in my tests. The cast version is three times slower and the `dateadd` versions are similar with my version slightly faster. `@gbn` Here is blog post for you :). [Bad Habits to Kick](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way now is:

```
select convert(datetime2(0) , getdate())
```

Comment: For those looking at this answer later....You could run into problems here. For example: SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), '2018-07-19 11:59:59.999')

Comment: @hyphen is this comment still valid? your example would yield 2018-07-19 12:00:00, which is the correct result in my eyes.

p.s. the midnight edge case works fine too. i.e. SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), '2018-07-19 23:59:59.999' gives 2018-07-20 00:00:00

Comment: As the first comment suggests, this answer does _not_ truncate seconds. It rounds to the nearest. If you need to truncate seconds, don't use this answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
convert(datetime, convert(varchar, @datetime_var, 120), 120)
```

Comment: Slightly more terse is: CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 120) AS DATETIME)

Answer (score 4):

The following has very fast performance, but it not only removes millisecond but also rounds to minute. See (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)

```
select cast(yourdate as smalldatetime) from yourtable
```

Edit:

The following script is made to compare the scripts from Mikael and gbn I upvoted them both since both answers are great. The test will show that gbn' script is slightly faster than Mikaels:

```
declare @a datetime
declare @x int = 1 
declare @mikaelend datetime

declare @mikael datetime = getdate() 
while @x < 5000000 
begin   
  select @a = dateadd(millisecond, -datepart(millisecond, getdate()), getdate()) , @x +=1 
end  
set @mikaelend = getdate()

set @x = 1 
declare @gbnend datetime
declare @gbn datetime = getdate() 
while @x < 5000000
begin 
  select @a = DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, '20000101', getdate()), '20000101')  , @x +=1 
end  
set @gbnend = getdate()
select datediff(ms, @mikael, @mikaelend) mikael, datediff(ms, @gbn, @gbnend) gbn
```

First run

```
mikael      gbn
----------- -----------
5320        4686
```

Second run

```
mikael      gbn
----------- -----------
5286        4883
```

Third run

```
mikael      gbn
----------- -----------
5346        4620
```

Comment: `smalldatetime` truncates to the minute. (Not sure if I am saying that quite right, maybe I should say it rounds to the minute). See the example in (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx). Don't want to downvote you because this was what I tried, so at first glance it *looks* like the right answer -- so maybe helpful to leave this.

Comment: You are right, my bad. smalldatetime shows the seconds but it is always 0

Comment: This would be more fair. `select datediff(ms, @mikael, @gbn) gbn, datediff(ms, @gbn, getdate()) mikael`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I had messed up the test. It has been corrected now.

Comment: Running this test today gives me opposite results: mikael: 2426 gbn: 2950 // mikael: 2400 gbn: 2963 // mikael: 2450 gbn: 3010

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @dt datetime2
set @dt = '2019-09-04 17:24:05.784' 
select convert(datetime2(0), @dt)
```

Comment: This rounds the milliseconds rather than truncating them. The question asks for a method that would convert `2012-01-25 17:24:05.784` to `2012-01-25 17:24:05` where this answer would yield `2012-01-25 17:24:06`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on accepted answer by @Mikael Eriksson:

To truncate a datetime2(7) to 3 places (aka milliseconds):

```
   -- Strip of fractional part then add desired part back in
   select dateadd(nanosecond,
                  -datepart(nanosecond, TimeUtc) + datepart(millisecond, TimeUtc) * 1e6,
                  TimeUtc) as TimeUtc
```

The current max precision of datetime2(p) is (7) (from [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql))

Answer (score 0):

```
--- DOES NOT Truncate milliseconds
--- 2018-07-19 12:00:00.000
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-07-19 11:59:59.999')  

--- Truncate milliseconds
--- 2018-07-19 11:59:59.000
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(19), '2018-07-19 11:59:59.999', 126)) 

--- Current Date Time with milliseconds truncated
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(19), GETDATE(), 126))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST( LEFT( '2018-07-19 11:59:59.999' , 19 ) AS DATETIME2(0) )
```