# Why can't I use a datetime parameter in ssrs?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS Date/Time parameter generated from a shared dataset query against a SQL Server datetime field. The parameter displays correctly in a report textbox but it will not work in an embedded dataset query, even against the same table that the datetime value was generated from.

In order to use the parameter for a dataset query I have to parse both sides of a where clause to get it to work in Preview in SSDT:

```
(convert(varchar,invoice.snapshot_datetime,120)) = (convert(varchar,@snapshotdatetime,120))
```

This is tremendously inefficient.

How can I get my where clause to work without parsing the `invoice.snapshot_datetime` column?

Server Details

- The SQL Server Language is English (United States).
- SQL Server `dateformat` is `mdy` (from `dbcc useroptions`).
- `Getdate()` returns `'2015-05-20 10:27:56.687'` in SSMS

Comment: If the data type of both the column and the variable is the same, why do you convert them at all?

Comment: its working fine in my end I have created a Report using DateTime Parameter and it fetch the data what i want my be there is some otrher problem in your end .please do not pass parameter value with single Quote .

Comment: @ZoharPeled - if I don't convert then the two sides don't equate

Comment: @ArunGairola - my parameter is created from a shared dataset. I have updated the question. Parameters are being passed without quotes.

Comment: What is your desired time resolution? Do you need exact seconds, minutes, hours or just date?

Comment: @ZoharPeled date & hours & minutes are sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your date range is between 1900-01-01 and 2079-06-06 you can cast to [`SmallDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx) to truncate the seconds out of your `datetime` variable:

```
DECLARE @DateTime datetime
SET @DateTime = CAST(CAST(@snapshotdatetime as SmallDateTime) as DateTime)
```

(thanks to [t-clausen.dk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/806969/t-clausen-dk) for [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9019401/3094533))

Now, since your actual column is of type [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), it does keep seconds (and milliseconds), and you will need to eliminate them as well.
However, using functions on your column will prevent the SQL Server from using any indexes you might have on this column, so a better approach would be to use a `DateTime` range:

```
DECLARE @FromDateTime datetime, @ToDateTime datetime
SET @FromDateTime = CAST(CAST(@snapshotdatetime as SmallDateTime) as DateTime)
```

Since the cast will round the minutes of the small date time up if it's over 29.998 seconds, and down if it's below 29.999 seconds. You always want to round down since it's *From* datetime, you need to cheke if you need to decrease a minute:

```
IF datepart(second, @snapshotdatetime) > 29 
OR (datepart(second, @snapshotdatetime) = 29 
    AND datepart(millisecond, @snapshotdatetime) > 998)
SET @FromDateTime = DATEADD(minute, -1, @FromDateTime)

SET @ToDateTime = DATEADD(minute, 1, @FromDateTime)
```

and then, in your where clause, use this:

```
invoice.snapshot_datetime <= @FromDateTime 
AND invoice.snapshot_datetime >= @ToDateTime
```

Comment: thanks, this is what was requested. And it would help with performance. But I would prefer to use an EQUALS operator.

Comment: The point of using the `between...and` is to get the minute resulotion. Using `=` will force you to convert the colum as you do now or using exact time including milliseconds. You can't eat the cake and keep it as well...

Comment: Maybe that is the core of the problem? That the SSRS Date/Time parameter doesn't hold milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found solution yet, try this:

```
select (convert(varchar,GETDATE(),112))
```

it will return 20180206 (yyymmdd)