# How to use DATE() in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm trying to recreate this expression from excel in SSRS:

=((TODAY()-DATE(2016,7,1))/(DATE(2021,6,30) - DATE(2016,7,1)))*100

But I'm getting an error that says date can't be used as a function in SSRS. DateValue converts it to a string and I need to calculate the percentage of time that's elapsed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I use a datetime parameter in ssrs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344543/why-cant-i-use-a-datetime-parameter-in-ssrs)

Comment: @TomJohn - these questions don't seem similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **Date** function in SSRS - I think you actually want the **DateSerial** function.

The date serial function converts a year, month, and day values into a date. You might need to use **DateDiff** in your calculation - I don't remember if SSRS lets you subtract dates.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateDiff()` and `CDate()`:

```
=(DateDiff("d", Now(), CDate("07.01.2016")) / DateDiff("d", CDate("30.06.2021"), CDate("07.01.2016")) *100
```

Comment: This wont work in the OP's case as his date is 3 separate numbers. Hannover FIst's answer is correct, `DATESERIAL` should be used.

Comment: Yes you are right, should have used `DateSerial()` instead of `CDate()`