# Consolidating rows based off Timestamp Values for maintenance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several tables that contain information that are time stamps at irregular and very frequent intervals, sometimes several within a second. I'm looking to consolidate the data by creating another query to reduce the size of the main SQL server. I'd like to create several of these that'll consolidate further as the data ages.

For example, the data is less than 24 hours old, I'd like to have granularity to the second. If the data is a month old, the granularity becomes an within the hour.

Log Table:

| EquID | CellID | StnID | Time | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:04.240 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:05.890 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:05.223 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:06.940 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:06.240 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:07.860 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:07.237 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:08.800 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:08.207 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:09.740 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:09.220 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:10.730 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:10.217 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:11.650 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:11.207 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:12.650 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:12.200 | 1 |
| 4241 | 10 | 5 | 2022-07-15 11:24:13.560 | 1 |

Expected Result:

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What would be best for to add for this @Larnu? ASCII table?

Comment: DDL and DML would be best, then a markdown table, and lastly a well formatted tabular `text` table.

Comment: All set? Or should the expected result look like this as well?

Comment: So really your question is how can you truncate a datetime to seconds. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018993/truncate-datetime-to-second-remove-milliseconds-in-t-sql).

Comment: Yes, @SeanLange, I'm attempting to truncate the data within a range, but also need to sum the counts while doing so to reduce the overall number of rows. I'd like to be able to do this within X time range in the future. I.e. If I have 3 rows at 11:25:03.xxx  with count 1 the query will reduce it to one row with a count of 3 at 11:25:03.000

Comment: Right this is what aggregation does. If you truncate your dates the count will work. I was going to try to demonstrate this but it is not clear what  you want. If the data is less than 24 hours old you want it truncated to the second. Then if it is older than a month you want it grouped by month. What about the data between 24 hours and a month?

Comment: If I could get an example for just the 24 hours truncated to the second, I could more than likely figure out the rest. We haven't established what we'll need to aggregate these to long term to reduce data size.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I've come up with as a solution. I'm certain there's a cleaner way of accomplishing this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Test_Table]')
            AND name = 'ConsolidateID'
            )
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE Test_Table
            ADD ConsolidateID int NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
    END

INSERT INTO Test_Table
(EquID, CellID, StnID, Time, Count, ProdCode, ConsolidateID)
    SELECT 
        EquID,
        CellID,
        StnID,
        dateadd(MILLISECOND, -datepart(MILLISECOND, [Time]), [Time]),
        Count,
        ProdCode,
        ConsolidateID = 0
    FROM LogGood

INSERT INTO Test_Table
(EquID, CellID, StnID, Time, Count, ProdCode, ConsolidateID)
    SELECT 
        EquID,
        CellID,
        StnID,
        dateadd(MILLISECOND, -datepart(MILLISECOND, [Time]), [Time]),
        sum(Count),
        ProdCode,
        ConsolidateID = ConsolidateID + 1
    FROM Test_Table
    Group by EquID,CellID,StnID,Time,ProdCode, ConsolidateID
    Order By [Time]

DELETE FROM Test_Table
WHERE ConsolidateID <> 1
```

I had to do a "double" insert as I couldn't get a `GROUP BY [Time]` to work after the first insert from `LogGood`. I then just created and ID number to be able to remove duplicate rows.